# Apache log lines appearing out of sequence - why?

Tags: apache

I've got an apache web server, and when a certain user accesses a certain page I get a log line who's timestamp is out of sync.

Sample output:

```
IP1 - - [22/Jun/2009:12:20:40 +0000] "GET URL1" 200 3490 "REFERRING_URL1" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022)"

IP2 - - [22/Jun/2009:12:11:47 +0000] "GET URL2" 200 17453 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv:1.9.0.11) Gecko/2009060214 Firefox/3.0.11"

IP3 - - [22/Jun/2009:12:20:41 +0000] "GET URL3" 200 889 "REFERRING_URL2" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; GTB6; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; 3P_USEC 1.0.11.2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618)"
```

(I've anonymised requesting IPs - IP1, IP2 and IP3, requested URLs - URL1, URL2 and URL3, and the two referrrer URLs)

As can be seen the three lines (which appeared in the log in this order), are out of sync. This only happens when IP2 requests URL2 - all other logs seem normal.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The logs are written when the request is completed, so early long requests may be written after late short ones. Add `%D` to your LogFormat definition to see the time taken to serve the request, in microseconds.

See more [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats)

Comment: Is there a way to tell apache to write the log line when the request is started instead of the time when it is completed?

Comment: I don't think so, as many of the data (compute time, response size, etc) is known after the processing is over. Do you serve dynamic content? If so, have your code to write your own logs as the request starts

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that the time included on the line corresponds with the *start time* of the request. However, the line won't actually be written until the request is complete. So, in the case of OP's example, this means that the IP2/URL2 request took a long time to complete. (More precisely, probably just under 9 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're doing some kind of COMET requests?

My first thought is that the log only records the time at which the request finished? So maybe IP1's request took a while to complete but arrived before IP2's.  Only requests I know that behave that way are AJAXey Comet requests.

Probably not the correct answer, by maybe a clue.

**Edit**: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/apache-log-entries-order-516354/ confirms that the time in the log includes the time required to transfer the content to the browser.

Comment: Nope, nothing that exotic. Looking further, the device in question seems to be a mobile device (going by its IP), but it still seems strange that the page in question (about 210k in total) takes nearly 9 minutes to load.

Comment: Maybe not.  It could be lazy fetching data trying to conserve bandwidth. Forcing your server to keep things in memory until the page it needs the page transfered. (wild guess) I haven't seen this in the wild, but it makes sense.